# Hive lateral view with sample example with hive table having 1 column as array

Tags: view, hive, sample, query-by-example, lateral

My use case is I am having one table in hive which has one column as INT and one as Array data type. I want to display it horizontally..

Answer (score 17):

Explode function displays each element of collection data type as single row.

```
CREATE TABLE Products
(id INT, ProductName STRING, ProductColorOptions ARRAY<STRING>);
select * from products;
```

> 1 Watches [“Red”,”Green”]
>
> 2 Clothes [“Blue”,”Green”]
>
> 3 Books [“Blue”,”Green”,”Red”]

```
select explode(ProductColorOptions ) from products;
```

> Red
>
> Green

But I want to join with other columns like id but that leads to an error.

In that case, we need to use Lateral View.Lateral view creates a virtual table for exploded columns and make join with the base table.

We need not to worry about the virtual table as it is done by hive internally.

```
SELECT p.id,p.productname,colors.colorselection FROM default.products P
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(p.productcoloroptions) colors as colorselection;
```

> 1 Watches Red
>
> 1 Watches Green
>
> 2 Clothes Blue

Comment: What if we want to join a table to the one you have created at the end? It seems to be refused by hive

Answer (score 6):

Simple explanation, suppose your table having data like name  and qualification

Table content:

```
Amar    ["Btech","Mtech"]
Amala   ["Bsc","Msc","Mtech"]
Akash   ["Btech","Mba"]
```

Table Creation:

```
create table raw2(name string, qual  array<string>);
```

Query:

```
select name, myq from <table> lateral view explode(qual) q as myq;
```

Comment: Hi Ankur ,I have the same kind of data set and i am trying get multiple rows with the values in the array.

Answer (score 1):

creating table with name Favourites, id of int type, name of string type & fav_song of Array of String type.

```
hive> CREATE TABLE Favourites
> (id INT, Name STRING, fav_song ARRAY<STRING>);
```

In general, Lateral view distributes the array elements in sequential rows keeping the common rows as it is.

For Example:

```
hive> select * from Favourites;
```

**id    name    fav_song**

1   Akshay ['Rang De Basanti','Live it Up']

2   Sonal   ['All the Stars','1000 years']

The rows post the query will be displayed as:

```
hive> SELECT p.id,p.name,colors.my_fav_song FROM default.Favourites P
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(p.fav_song) fv as my_fav_song;
```

**id   name my_fav_song**

1   Akshay  Rang De Basanti

1   Akshay  Live it Up

2   Sonal   All the Stars

2   Sonal   1000 years

Comment: why do u have `colors` keyword in `SELECT p.id,p.name,colors.my_fav_song FROM default.Favourites P
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(p.fav_song) fv as my_fav_song;` query ?